# Firebase Authentication JavaScript get success

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

With the following Firebase email authentication code, how do you know whether authentication was successful?

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;

            if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
              alert('Wrong password.');
            } else {
              alert(errorMessage);         
            }

            console.log(error);
        });
```

I understand that it is easy to realise whether or not authentication was unsuccessful, however, how do I know if the user was able to login with their supplied credentials?  There doesn't seem to be a callback for a 'successful' log in.  I currently have a login form, and I want to navigate away on a successful log in.

Answer (score 27):

*firebaser here*

@ksav's answer show the preferred way of detecting when a user signs in our out.

For completeness I want to show the second way to detect this, which is in direct response to `signInWithEmailAndPassword`:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {
   // user signed in
}).catch(function(error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
        alert('Wrong password.');
    } else {
        alert(errorMessage);         
    }
    console.log(error);
});
```

The `then()` will be invoked when the user has signed in.

The reason we de-emphasize this approach in our documentation is that it will miss many situations. For example:

- when a user reloads the page, the `then()` will not be invoked. The `onAuthStateChanged()` callback on the other hand **will** be invoked then too.
- the a user gets signed out (for example if their short-lived token can't be refreshed), the `catch()` will not be invoked. The `onAuthStateChanged()` callback on the other hand **will** be invoked then too.

If you want to explicitly respond to when the user actively signed in, the approach in my answer might be useful. But in most cases, we recommend that you that the approach in @ksav's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Get the currently signed-in user

---

The recommended way to get the current user is by setting an observer on the Auth object:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Answer (score -1):

If nothing was cached then it was successful.

```
var isSuccessful = true
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var isSuccessful = false
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;

        if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
          alert('Wrong password.');
        } else {
          alert(errorMessage);         
        }

        console.log(error);
    })
    finally {
     if(isSuccessful)
         //Success!
    }
```

Comment: Just so everyone knows why this answer is downvoted - the signin is asynchronous. So it is no use testing the isSuccessful variable straight after the call to signInWithEmailAndPassword, you need to check if the login was successful in a .Then function