# React Native - Jest testing with firebase

Tags: firebase, testing, react-native, jestjs

I am a newbie in Firebase. I have read that it is good to unit test as you go. So this is what I have been trying to do lately. I currently have a problem when trying to test render on a class that uses Firebase. This is the following code I have been trying to fix:

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import MainTab from '../../components/MainTab';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <MainTab/>
    ).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

However, I am getting the following error on the test when trying to obtain the current user's id from firebase:
[image]

Has anyone stumbled into this error before? P.S. Don't go hard on me if this is something really vacuous, just trying to learn.

Comment: Seens like your `currentUser` is null in this moment. Could you put the part of your firebase user authentication?

Comment: This makes sense, yes. My user authenticates with email and password using the following: `onLogin() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => this.successfulLogin())`
}`
I have read that I need to mock the signInWithEmailAndPassword before that.However, I have no clue on how is this supposed to be done. My firebase is initialized through a local config in my project.

Comment: I put an example and a suggestion for you.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. signInWithEmailAndPassword

> `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` returns
>   `firebase.Promise` containing non-null `firebase.User`
>
> Asynchronously signs in using an email and password.
>
> This method will be deprecated and will be updated to resolve with a
>   firebase.auth.UserCredential as is returned in
>   [firebase.auth.Auth#signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword).

For now, the implementation for this method is in below:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {
   // user signed in
   // - user.displayName
   // - user.email
   // - user.uid // <---- the user's unique ID
})
```

- You can see `firebase.User` properties here:
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
- You can read more details about this question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39959002/3332734

#### 2. For your case...

If you need to test the email/password authentication, I suggest you to use a firebase "dev" project and testing with user credentials for this dev firebase project.

- Be careful, don't store your UID for other tests!
- Firebase dont't provides a test for authentication yet.

#### 3. Firebase beta to 1.0 version

Easier unit testing using a new [firebase-functions-test](https://github.com/Firebase/firebase-functions-test) npm module that simplifies writing unit tests.

See more about it in:

- [Launching Cloud Functions for Firebase v1.0](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/04/launching-cloud-functions-for-firebase-1-0.html)
- [Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions Migration Guide: Beta to version 1.0](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff)

I hope I have been useful!