# Callback after successful login in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use Firebase with a mostly pure HTML/CSS/Javascript application.

I am given the following function to handle signing into firebase (from their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth)).

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

There is clearly a function called to handle errors if they occur when someone tries to login.

My problem is that I want to have some logic occur right after a successful login in firebase (not only after an unsuccessful login). Is there a way to do this (such as a callback)?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data

Comment: @Herohtar yes this is a duplicate. I would like to leave this up though simply because I wasn't able to find that question when I was googling around

Comment: With the exact terms you used in your question - "Firebase login callback" - the linked question is the second result on Google. (First if you search SO specifically.)

Comment: Not the exact terms I used though. Try "callback after login firebase"

Comment: Only if you don't look further than one result... those terms still give a first result with a group of SO questions that includes that one, and it's in the top 4 for a site specific search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword) say that this method returns a `firebase.Promise`.

Promises are async and handled using callbacks `then( onSuccess, onFailure )`, and `catch( onFailure )` so you can use your logic in either.

Unfortunately documentation doesn't say what arguments will be passed to `onSuccess` method, but you can always try:

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword( email, password )
.then( function onSuccess( ...args ) {
  console.log( 'onSuccess', args );
} )
.catch( function onFailure( err ) {
  console.log( 'onFailure', err );
} );
```

**Edit** as pointed out by @Herohtar and answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39958673/344477 it looks like using the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` is not the optimal way to track `auth` state since it is not invoked after page refresh & etc.

The best way to track if user is logged in or not is `onAuthStateChanged` method.